# Passing Values from one class to another

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring, nsmutablearray, cross-reference

I am designing a slot machine project that has a second view for the high score page. For the most part, everything is working except for the passing of the winner from slot machine to the high score page. Here is my code in a method within slot machine:

```
if(win == YES)  {
    NSString *msg = nil;
    if(playerField.text.length > 0) {
        msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", playerField.text];
    }
    NSLog(@"DEBUG");
    [(HighScorePage *)self.view addNewHighScore:msg];
    [self performSelector:@selector(playWinSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
    [msg release];
}
```

And Here is the addNewHighScore method in HighScorePage:

```
-(void)addNewHighScore:(NSString *)player   {
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int i = 0;
for (NSArray *count in dynPlayerArray) {
    [tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i++ inSection:0]];
}
[tempArray addObject:player];
[[self highScores] beginUpdates];
[[self highScores] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[[self highScores] endUpdates];

[tempArray release];
```

}

Still new at this, so let me know what you think! Thanks!

Comment: where is this statement if(win == YES) ?

Comment: in my IBAction called spin, called everytime the user clicks a button. It makes my slot machine spin and play sounds and stuff. That is all function, all I need to know is how to pass a string from one class to another

Comment: that is all functioning*

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me, your High Score data should be in a model class everyone could access, like a singleton for example.

When your player wins, your slot ViewController should insert the new High Score in this model class and then, using whether Key-Value Observing or Notifications, the High Score view should update itself.

Comment: Is there a simpler way? I don't want to recreate this whole project to make it more efficient, I just need a method that works.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by how your code is organized. As I understand things, your first chunk is inside an Action of your spinner ViewController. What is HighScorePage ? It looks like a ViewController but you call it using self.view.

Comment: Both slotmachine and highscorepage are views of my tabbarcontroller. highScores is my UITableView hosting the values TBH this updating of UITableView doesn't make sense to me (I'm coming to this from Java). It seems that to populate UITableView, you need to use an NSArray, but NSArray isn't dynamic(can't append new objects). So it would make sense to use an NSMutableArray that can change, but Objective-C is stupid and doesn't want to accept that. I kind of hate this language lol.

Comment: 1/You are talking about ViewControllers, not views, the difference is really important and I think your main issue is the call to (HighScorePage *)this.view 2/Of course you can use an NSMutableArray as a data source for a UITableView, you can use anything you want as long as you can pump data from it and send it to your UITableView through the UITableViewDataSource protocol methods. 3/Please take a little while to understand the framework before hating it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just never been so frustrated with a language before.

Comment: Oh wait I am using a UIViewController, nvm

Comment: OK so all you have to do is reference your HighScoresViewController inside your SlotMachineViewController so you can call the addNewHighScore from there. A good way to do this is using a property or a simple instance variable declared in your .h file. Does this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you have asked for how to pass a string from one class to another, here is the answer -

IF you want to pass string value from class B to class A then in class A's .h file create an NSMutableString instance and define it as property as -

```
NSString *stringVar;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringVar;

and also synthesize this property in class A's .m file for setter & getter as-

@ synthesize stringVar;
```

then in class B access this string as class A's property and assign what value you want to pass from class B to class A.

Hope this will help you. Also for more info about property look -

http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1`enter code here`